# Cannot create Python Object in .NET with IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

Newly I started working with IronPython in .NET but as I saw some few examples they're making engine with `Python.CreateEngine()` But the `Python` object isn't loaded for me however I imported these references.

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
```

I searched around this topic but I couldn't find anything.

Peace Out!

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a tangent, but by far the quickest way of getting going with IronPython is to download a copy of [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) and use a project template to start you off.  You'll sidestep a lot of these initial environment issues.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll try it. But what's wrong with Visual Studio?

Comment: I installed it. It was a nice IDE. But after adding references still doesn't support `Python` object. I don't know! I think there is something wrong with my sources But I exactly got the last version of IronPython from codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually add the assemblies to your project?

Comment: Yup. I even searched into the Object Browser but nothing found.